# Android Emulator: Running Goldfish 3.4 Linux kernel too old to load a ram disk

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, kernel, qemu

I am trying to setup https://github.com/Fuzion24/AndroidKernelExploitationPlayground on Linux, the repository contains a vulnerable patch for 3.4 goldfish kernel. I have setup an android SDK revision 19 environment as follows : -

```
mkdir -p android-sdk-19/platforms
cd android-sdk-19/platforms
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-19_r04.zip
unzip *
rm android-19_r04.zip
cd ../

wget http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
unzip platform-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip 
rm platform-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip 

wget http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
unzip build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
rm build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip 

wget http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r19-linux.zip
unzip tools_r19-linux.zip 
rm tools_r19-linux.zip 

mkdir -p system-images/android-19
cd system-images/android-19

wget http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sysimg_x86-19_r02.zip
unzip sysimg_x86-19_r02.zip 
rm *.zip

mkdir -p ../../sources/android-19
cd ../../sources/android-19
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sources-19_r02.zip
unzip sources-19_r02.zip 
rm sources-19_r02.zip 

cd ../../

tools/android create avd --force -t "android-19" -n kernel_challenges --abi "x86"
```

After applying the patch and building the kernel image, I used the following command to run it on the emulator : -

```
android-sdk-19/tools/emulator \
-show-kernel -kernel goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
-avd kernel_challenges -no-boot-anim -no-skin -no-audio -no-window \
-qemu -monitor unix:/tmp/qemuSocket,server,nowait -s
```

But I receive the following error:

```
qemu: linux kernel too old to load a ram disk 
goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage, 
android-sdk-19/system-images/android-19/x86//ramdisk.img, 
qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish 
clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 android.bootanim=0 ndns=1
```